How to Efficiently Index and Search Arrays with UNNEST in PostgreSQL
I have a products table with an array column tags that contains up to 700 elements.
I want to efficiently search for specific tag names for a given user to be used in a search bar.
Here's my query:
SELECT tags
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT unnest(tags) AS tags
    FROM products
    WHERE user_id = :id AND tags IS NOT NULL AND cardinality(tags) > 0
) AS unnested_tags
WHERE tags LIKE '%:search%';

I initially created this index to improve performance:
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_products_user_id_tags
ON products(user_id, tags);

However, I encountered the following error:
ERROR: index row size 3240 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704
DETAIL: Index row references tuple (50426,2) in relation "products".
HINT: Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

Most likely due to the tags size.
To address this, I attempted to create the following partial index, but it didn't work:
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_products_user_id_tags_partial
ON products(user_id, tags)
WHERE array_length(tags, 1) <= 100;

Which Indexing Approach is Best for My Use Case?
Key Points

Moving tags to a separate table is not feasible at this time.
Partial matches are needed, but exact matches can be considered if they significantly improve query performance.
Tag length ranges from 1 to over 700 strings.
Any tag value can be used greater of equal to 3 characters.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions!

You might want to try a GIN or GiST index on the array, but the array will still be a challenge. Better to normalize your data, that's what works best in relational databases like PostgreSQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html

Move the tags to a join table.

@Schwern Unfortunately, moving the data to a separate table, which I agree is the best solution, is not possible, at least for now.

@soltex Can you explain why you say it's not possible? There are ways to maintain backwards compatibility.

@Schwern because it would break a few key parts of the codebase, I rather to leave it as is for now, and normalize the data later, if possible

@soltex A view may be able to take care of that. If you show us some examples of your required queries, you'll open up more possible answers.

You have two challenges here, first the array and second the LIKE in the where condition. A GiST or GIN index could solve the array problem, but not the LIKE problem. For that you need the pg_trgm extension, but that doesn't work on arrays. You could replace your current table by a view and that view is using a normalized data model. Your current code that expects an array gets an array, but under the hood you have a proper 3NF data model. That can be indexed and delivers the performance you need.

You can try WHERE array_to_string(tags,',') LIKE '%:search%' without unnest array. Common indexes won't help you.

If you cannot refactor the data, can you at least refactor the query?  If you can't change either one, then I don't think any index can help you (beyond what an index just on user_id will do, which I assume you already tried)

@jjanes yes, I can refactor the query, what do you suggest?

If you can afford the storage space, add the table with one tag per row, plus a trigger on your main table (keep it) to sync them. That way everyone can still use the array, and whoever needs any sort of ~, can use its normalised version. If individual tags may be long, consider full text search, making that 2 added tables: one with tsvector_ops for whole multi-word tags, another with gin_trgm_ops on distinct words in them, to check for misspelling.

First things first: WHERE tags LIKE '%:search%' (if it was legal syntax) also returns partial matches. Is that intended? Or do you really filter for exact tag names? Postgres version? SELECT version(); Exact table definition (CREATE TABLE statement) How many rows in your table? Table size? (SELECT pg_relation_size('products'); Predominant read / write patterns? Min & max length of your tag names? Can any tag name be used, or is there a set of allowed tags?

@ErwinBrandstetter Yes, partial matches are intended, but I can consider using exact matches if that substantially speeds up the query. The minimum length is 1, and the maximum is 700+. Any tag can be used, but I should probably restrict results to tags greater than 3 characters. I've added the following to the inner query WHERE ... tags IS NOT NULL AND cardinality(tags) > 0 AND and it helped.

@soltex: Please [edit] the question with the requested info. Comments are insufficient.

@ErwinBrandstetter done! thanks for asking

I was asking for min/max length of tag names. (Plus avg.) The objective of the query isn't yet entirely clear to me. "I want to efficiently search for specific tag names for a given user to be used in a search bar." Can you be more specific? If partial matches are optional I wonder all the more. You just want to search the single array from the row of the given user? For what exactly?

The output of the UNNEST construct is unindexable, except via a materialized view in which case it is no longer the output of UNNEST.
You could test the rows which might pass the test before unnesting, and then unnest and test again for the individual tags of the array which triggered the pass.  The best way to do this is probably with the parray_gin extension.
SELECT distinct tags
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(tags) AS tags
    FROM products
    WHERE user_id = :id and tags @@> array['%:search%']
) AS unnested_tags
WHERE tags LIKE '%:search%';

Which would be supported by an index such as:
create index on products using gin (user_id, tags parray_gin_ops);

Alternatively, it could use a parray_gin index like the above with only the tags column, and a separate btree index on user_id, automatically combined with a BitmapAnd (which is probably what I would prefer--multicolumn gin indexes have few benefits over multiple single-column ones, and much worse observability.)
The performance of this is going to depend on how selective user_id is, and how selective the tag pattern-match is, and how many trigrams are contained in the search pattern. Among other things.  If it uses the index but is still too slow, you would need to share an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for further analysis.
